# Viewing a specific time point of an ODE plot in python

Tags: python, ode

I have this ODE system

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Total population, N.
N = 1000
# Initial number of infected and recovered individuals, I0 and R0.
I0, R0 = 1, 0
# Everyone else, S0, is susceptible to infection initially.
S0 = N - I0 - R0
# Contact rate, beta, and mean recovery rate, gamma, (in 1/days).
beta, gamma = 2/7, 1/7
# A grid of time points (in days)
t = np.linspace(0, 160, 160)

# The SIR model differential equations.
def deriv(y, t, N, beta, gamma):
    S, I, R = y
    dS = ((-beta * S * I) / N)
    dI = ((beta * S * I) / N) - (gamma * I)
    dR = (gamma * I)
    return dS, dI, dR

# Initial conditions are S0, I0, R0
# Integrate the SIR equations over the time grid, t.
solve = odeint(deriv, (S0, I0, R0), t, args=(N, beta, gamma))
S, I, R = solve.T

# Plot the data on three separate curves for S(t), I(t) and R(t)
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='w')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor='#dddddd', axisbelow=True)
ax.plot(t, S, 'b', alpha=1, lw=2, label='Susceptible')
ax.plot(t, I, 'r', alpha=1, lw=2, label='Infected')
ax.plot(t, R, 'black', alpha=1, lw=2, label='Recovered')
ax.set_xlabel('Time in days')
ax.set_ylabel('Number (1000s)')
#ax.set_ylim(0,1.1)
#ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(length=0)
#ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(length=0)
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', c='w', lw=2, ls='-')
legend = ax.legend()
legend.get_frame().set_alpha(0.5)
#for spine in ('top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'):
#    ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

Which gives this

[image]

However, say if for the recovered curve, I wanted to see the time point up to day 80 minus the time point up to day 79. Then it gives me the count for that day on day 80. Is it possible to plot this. I tried using

```
ax.plot(t, R[80], 'black', alpha=1, lw=2, label='Recovered')
```

but this gives an error

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (160,) and (1,)
```

edit - Pranav, yes, I wish to plot the plot curve for a single day.

Comment: Of course it will give you an error, `t` is the entire array of all times, `R[80]` is _one single point_. How would you get _only the `[80]` index of `t`?

Comment: If you want the _difference_ between day 80 and 79, you need to plot _that_! `ax.plot(t[1:], np.diff(R))` or `ax.plot(80, R[80] - R[79])`

Comment: Your question is unclear -- do you want to plot `R` for a single day, or the difference between consecutive `R` for all days, or just the difference for a single day? Please also edit your title so that it summarizes your question.

Comment: Yes, what I meant was the difference between day 80 and 79. But with the line of code `ax.plot(t[1:], np.diff(R))`, how do I specify the time frames? the second ax.plot you suggested does not work,

Comment: What do you mean "specify time frames"?

Comment: For example, with the line `np.diff(R))` what difference is it taking? I wish to take the value of that curve at 80, and subtract the value of 79 from it, and plot the result. so I tried `ax.plot(t[1:], np.diff(R[80]-R[79]))` however it returns `ValueError: diff requires input that is at least one dimensional`

Comment: Do you want a plot like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhuY8.png Note the circles at x=80

Comment: _"with the line np.diff(R)) what difference is it taking?"_: When `x = np.diff(y)`, you have `x[i] = y[i+1] - y[i]`. So when you `plot(t[1:], np.diff(R))`, you plot `i + 1` on the x axis vs `R[i + 1] - R[i]` on the y axis, so you get a plot like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiVpY.png

Comment: Note that if you want the time steps to be exactly 1, you need to define `t = np.linspace(0,160,160+1)`.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I still don't understand. If I want to plot the increase/decrease in R in just one day, how can that be achieved? In your code it doesn't specify a time point to view that day's change in

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. `r_diff = np.diff(R)` gives you the difference between consecutive elements of `R`, i.e. the day-to-day change in `R`. This is an array. If you want the change between day `i` and `i + 1`, you look at `r_diff[i]`.

Comment: I understand the difference function here, but my error is in the plot. I used `ax.plot(t[1:], r_diff[i])` where `i` is any day I specify, though it errors me ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

Comment: @Landon `ax.plot(t[79:81], R[79:81]` Does this solve your problem? You can also highlight just this area in your overall plot as `ax.plot(t[79:81], R[79:81], 'yellow', alpha=1, lw=2, label='__no_legend__')`. For this just solve your ODE at `t =np.linspace(0,160,160+1) `.